# (keycloak-js) Failed to initialize adapter, keycloak.init doesn't work

Tags: javascript, vuejs3, keycloak, keycloak-js

I'm using npm packet keycloak-js in vue 3 app.
Keycloak server and keycloak-js with same versions 24.0.2

```
import Keycloak from 'keycloak-js'

let initOptions = {
  url: 'https://address'
  realm: 'myrealm',
  clientId: 'myapp'
}

  let keycloak = new Keycloak(initOptions);

try {
  const authenticated = await keycloak.init({ onLoad: 'login-required', checkLoginIframe: false });
  console.log(`User is ${authenticated ? 'authenticated' : 'not authenticated'}`);
} catch (error) {
  console.error('Failed to initialize adapter:', error);
}
```

Error in console is "Failed to initialize adapter: undefined"

In browser I found this

> "Cookies with the SameSite=None; Secure and not Partitioned attributes that operate in cross-site contexts are third-party cookies. In future Chrome versions, reading third-party cookies will be blocked. This behavior protects user data from cross-site tracking."

Affected resources is keycloak cookies and token, so probably this is reason.

Token status 401, but on Keycloack server I can see that session appeared.

By searching solution I found that `checkLoginIframe: false` can help, but it isn't.

Can anyone advise on this issue please, why `keycloak.init()` doesn't work and how I can fix it?

Comment: Issue resolved. it was issue with enabled confidential mode on Keycloak server, Changes confidential to Public in clientID - this is resolved issue

Answer (score 0):

Issue resolved. it was issue with enabled confidential mode on Keycloak server, Changes confidential to Public in clientID - this is resolved issue